# How to reduce space between two columns in html table

Tags: html, datatables

I am using data table for displaying data from the database. There is some space between two columns of the data table. How to reduce the space between them. I tried cellspacing but it is deprecated in html5. Is there any possible way to do this.

Comment: First - provide the code. Second - did you try to reduce the padding?

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS:

```css
Table 
{
  border_collapse:
    seperate;
  table {padding: 0}
  }
```

Comment: What's the point of a live demo consisting of CSS without any HTML to apply it to? (The CSS is invalid too).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse}
table td {padding: 0}
```